# How to disable Windows 10 Microsoft Edge download recommendation?

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

When I click upper right cross it reappears after some time.
[image]

Comment: The best way is actually downloading and installing Edge to replace the aging IE.

Comment: I already replaced IE and Edge with Chrome. And I have no plans installing Edge.

Comment: So, if you actually uninstalled IE the reminder shouldn't apper. But perhaps you forgot about that step?

Comment: I did not say "uninstalled". I said "replaced". It still exists but replaced with Chrome. The question is not how to download Edge, but how to disable this annoying add.

Comment: Again, uninstall IE -or- install Edge. It's this simple. If you want to use a Microsoft browser then use Edge, not IE because it has been superseded. If you don't want to use a Microsoft browser at all then there's no point in keeping the old IE around.

Comment: There is now little to choose from between Chromium Edge and Chrome. Chromium Edge cannot be fully uninstalled. So download and install Chromium Edge, let it replace IE, and then make Chrome your default browser.

Comment: @dereks Internet Explorer should not be installed period - it hasn't been safe to use for ~4yrs and any system with it still installed can be actively exploited due to a file association specific to IE which is not, and will not be, patched. If requiring IE for legacy businesses cloud software, use [IE Tab](https://www.ietab.net/) in a Chromium-based browser. IE can be uninstalled via `optional features` and it will no longer be available relatively quickly, being permanently removed from Windows, per Microsoft's recent press release (they stated explicitly in 2017 IE should no longer be used)

Comment: @John You don't need Edge to stop seeing the advert, IE simply needs to be uninstalled via `optionalfeatures` _(Win10 auto-uninstalled IE in a bi-annual update years ago and would have to have been manually installed by the user)_

Comment: **Windows 10 absolutely did NOT uninstall IE11 in an update years ago**, since it’s installed on my current production system running 21H1.  Additionally, uninstalling IE11, won’t stop that Edge recommendation.  That can only be done by disabling “Get tips, tricks, and suggestions as you use Windows” within Settings. Microsoft didn’t even announce the sunset on IE11 until this past week

Comment: With that said, it’s impossible to prevent Legacy Edge from being installed and the new Chromium Edge installed if you keep your system updated.  21H1 only has IE11 and Edge (Chromium) installed

Comment: By the way, Chromium Edge replaces Legacy Edge not IE11, shocked at the amount of disinformation in the commentary.  Just learned that IE11 is removed in build 21387  but that’s an Insider Preview build for 21H2 possibly 22H1 (since it’s a Dev channel it doesn’t belong to a specific release yet)

Comment: Unfortunately I've already turned off "Get tips, tricks, and..."

Answer (score 0):

This is updating Legacy Edge with new Chromium (Chrome based) Edge. This is not really a download notification, this is like windows update and in 20H2 they actually (while not removing Legacy Edge) stopped the ability to start Legacy Edge. Just like Legacy Edge it is part of protected storage and thus it is impossible to really do anything about it. Even now in 21H1 it is impossible to remove it.

Comment: Not sure about *impossible* ;) .. but ok.. I get your point.  I guarantee that it *could be* surgically removed.